# Replacing old incandescent fixture with LED and can't get it to work

Tags: wiring, led, replacement

I've got two incandescent can lights in series on the same circuit and I'm trying to replace them with LED fixtures. On my first attempt neither of the LEDs would come on so thinking they may be faulty I got two more. No luck. Called an electrician friend who told me I needed to replace the dimmer switch. Did that. Still no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include pictures of the wiring at both light fixtures and at the switch. 1) Turn off the power. 2) Pull devices from the wall. 3) Do NOT disconnect any wires. 4) take clear, focused pictures of all the wiring attached to the devices and where they go into cables at the back of the box. Also, if this is a dimmer switch, then yes that could be the problem, "plain" dimmers that work for incandescent bulbs won't work well with LED bulbs, but wiring pics first.

Comment: Your friend may be right.  Are your LED fixtures called out as dimmer-compatible?  And are they compatible with the switch you have?

Answer (score 3):

Lights are wired in parallel, not series.  Try a simple regular on/off switch first, if that doesn't work, something is really wrong.

To get dimming, both the LED lights AND the dimmer must be LED/dimmer compatible.

Comment: This answer is a good clue for the question poster. Older incandescent lights could very well have actually wired in series and still give out a reduced amount of light each even with the dimmer set at 100%. The LED lights rated to operate at line voltage will not work when wired in series and could even be damaged by connecting them this way.

Comment: True, if they were actually in series (I did consider that before posting) a 60 watt bulb incandescent bulb would put out as much light as a 30 watt bulb.  Assuming there are two bulbs in the chain.   And the LEDs would not work.  But even in really old houses, I've never heard of it or seen it.

Comment: I guess it may depend upon who installed them.

Comment: @MichaelKaras  And if they were in series, if one bulb burned out, neither would light.